# Android Source Code Project build failing

Tags: android, android-source

Trying to build AOSP

I have followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-android-roms-on-ubuntu-16-04) exactly on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine.
All commands leading up-to `make -j4` have been successful, however when I build it fails at 11% with the following error:

```
[ 11% 9531/83760] target thumb C: nfc_nci.bullhea..._32 <= system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.c
FAILED: out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/nfc_nci.bullhead_intermediates/hal/phNxpNciHal.o 
/bin/bash -c "PWD=/proc/self/cwd prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4053586/bin/clang  -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/utils -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/inc -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/common -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/dnld -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/hal -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/log -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/tml -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/self-test -I system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x -I out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/nfc_nci.bullhead_intermediates -I out/target/product/bullhead/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/nfc_nci.bullhead_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper \$(cat out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/nfc_nci.bullhead_intermediates/import_includes)  -I system/core/include -I system/media/audio/include -I hardware/libhardware/include -I hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -I hardware/ril/include -I libnativehelper/include -I frameworks/native/include -I frameworks/native/opengl/include -I frameworks/av/include -isystem out/target/product/bullhead/obj/include -isystem device/lge/bullhead/kernel-headers -isystem hardware/qcom/msm8994/kernel-headers -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/scsi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/uapi -c  -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -no-canonical-prefixes -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd= -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-expansion-to-defined -fdebug-prefix-map=\$PWD/= -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=date-time -nostdlibinc -msoft-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -D__ARM_FEATURE_LPAE=1 -target arm-linux-androideabi -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin   -std=gnu99 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing   -DPN547C2=1 -DPN548C2=2 -DPN551=3 -DPN553=4 -DNFC_NXP_CHIP_TYPE=PN548C2 -DANDROID -DNXP_UICC_ENABLE -DNXP_HW_SELF_TEST -DNFC_NXP_HFO_SETTINGS=FALSE -fPIC -D_USING_LIBCXX -DANDROID_STRICT   -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=return-type -MD -MF out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/nfc_nci.bullhead_intermediates/hal/phNxpNciHal.d -o out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/nfc_nci.bullhead_intermediates/hal/phNxpNciHal.o system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.c"
system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.c:2637:22: error: no member named 'nci_data' in 'struct phNxpNciHal_Control'

  if (nxpncihal_ctrl.nci_data.nci_version == NCI_VERSION_2_0) {
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
10:02:33 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (06:37 (mm:ss)) ####
```

What am I missing here? I have executed a `repo sync` in-case some files are missing, and a `make clean`.

```
Virtual machine stats:
    CPUs- 4-cores (Host: Intel Xeon E3-1575M : 8-cores)
    RAM - 20GB (Host: 32GB)
    HDD - 100GB
```

Build settings:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-8.0.0_r33 --depth=1
...
lunch aosp_bullhead-userdebug
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/android-8.0.0_r33/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.c

File location: path_to_aosp_oreo/system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.c

Line: 2637

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/android-8.0.0_r33/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.h

line: 66-101

There is not **nci_data** in **typedef struct phNxpNciHal_Control** only **nci_info**
I think that you must edit line 2637 from

```
  if (nxpncihal_ctrl.nci_data.nci_version == NCI_VERSION_2_0)
```

to

```
  if (nxpncihal_ctrl.nci_info.nci_version == NCI_VERSION_2_0)
```

---

Or change version to **8.1.0_r18** or higher

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/android-8.1.0_r18/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.c

in line: 2623

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/android-8.1.0_r18/halimpl/pn54x/hal/phNxpNciHal.h

in line: 66-101

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed the problem (Modifying Line 2637). I am still unsure as to why it needed to be modified in the first place. This is my first time building `lunch aosp_bullhead-userdebug`, `aosp_arm-eng` never required such modification.

Comment: After 2 hours building, it is successful 100%.

Comment: Any clues as to why this is required to be modified to work on a standard setup? All seems well when building after the modification, however the device fails to boot if this image is loaded.